# docker-composeでmysqlコンテナが立ち上がらない時の対処法を教えてください

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose

rails + mysqlの環境で動いているwebアプリケーションの開発にて
私の使用しているPCが、m1チップのmacbookなのですが、mysqlコンテナが立ち上がらず、原因を調べたところ、m1のmacでmysqlイメージを使用するには
`platform: linux/x86_64`
という記載をdocker-compose.ymlに追加しないといけないとのことでした。

なので、docker-compose.ymlに　`platform: linux/x86_64`を追記することで環境は立ち上がりました

[修正内容]

```
services:
  db:
    image: mysql5.7
    platform: linux/x86_64   # この行を追記しました
```

こちらで環境は立ち上がったのですが、こちらをリモートリポジトリにpushしてしまうと、m1のmacを使用していない作業者のimageのビルドが失敗してしまうのではないかと思い、現在、作業は、docker-compose.ymlをpushしないで作業を行っており、このような状況はあまり良くないのかなと思っています。

このように、docker-compose.ymlや、Dockerfileで、m1のmacを使用している作業者にのみ必要な設定が発生した場合、どのようにして、環境構築を行うべきなのでしょうか？

Answer (score 0):

`platform: linux/x86_64` という指定は、むしろ arm64 環境である M1 Mac において x86_64 がエミュレートできるので x86_64 で動かせるというお話であって、x86_64 環境である Intel Mac においてはこの記述のままで動くはず……です。

手元に環境が無いので試せませんが、Intel Mac をお持ちの他の作業者の方に動くか試してもらうのが早そうです。